# Como consigo puxar o poup-up do CAPTCHA com JavaScript para dentro do meu formulário no meu sistema de gestão ERP?

Tags: javascript, c#, captcha

O http://www.sintegra.gov.br/ é um site do governo com informações públicas sobre empresas.

Ao acessar o site preciso informar o CNPJ, selecionar a UF do CNPJ e preencher o CAPTCHA...[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero saber como consigo fazer aparecer essa caixa do CAPTCHA para o usuário preencher isso, dentro do meu sistema de gestão. 
Exemplo: Usuário está na tela de cadastro de clientes e ao preencher o campo CNPJ apareça um poup-up do CAPTCHA que ao ser preenchido corretamente eu consiga pegar as informações daquele CNPJ que estão dentro do site do SINTEGRA (Inscrição Estadual, logradouro etc...)

O sistema de gestão está desenvolvido em C# e eu quero fazer essa validação em JavaScript!

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Luciano, você não consegue pegar somente o captcha da página mas você pode exibir toda página para o usuário dentro de um WebBrowser e trabalhar os eventos deste browser e já preencher o conteúdo que você quer como CNPJ por exemplo.

Exemplo:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
webBrowser.Url = new Uri("endereco_do_site_aqui");
```

No método `WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted` você pode trabalhar a página para pegar os elementos HTML e setar informações no input:

```
private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Url.ToString() == "endereco_da_pagina_de_entrada")
      {
            //----- Observe que aqui você vai estar trabalhando com o html da página, verifique na página o nome do elemento que você tem que manipular
           HtmlElement cnpj = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("cnpj");
           cnpj.SetAttribute("value", seu_cnpj_a_ser_informado);
      }
}
```

Toda vez que o usuário navegar pela página este evento é disparado, com isso você consegue pegar todos os retornos.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado.